# java code throws error after uploading on Amazon AWS cloud services

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services

```
 Instances train1 = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\jacx.arff"))); 
    int lastIndex = train1.numAttributes() - 1;
    train1.setClassIndex(lastIndex);
```

This code runs properly on localhost but after uploading Amazon AWS it gives error.

> "jacx.arff" file is not uploaded to aws.

how to upload it???
and tell me how to read uploaded file.

Comment: What kind of AWS service do you use?

Comment: And generally this is not a good practice to have "hardcoded" file paths. On different machines/environments you can have different systems and filepaths/urls. The place where files are stored should be configurable. You can use e.g. environment variable to pass the current path of a file

Comment: what is the path for d:\\jacx.arff on aws? Did you move jacx.arff  to aws?

Comment: actully d://jacx.arff is local path but i dont get where the jack.arff file is store on aws